# MySQL: Select with Coalesce still returning null

Tags: mysql, coalesce

My understanding of COALESCE is that it returns the first non null value. I’m using COALESCE in the select statement below, but it’s still returning null. How can I fix it or is there a better way?

SET NEW.random = ( SELECT coalesce(animals)
FROM list
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 );

DB Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aca780246b24ec4cce8d9978c1113d26

Comment: What is the point of `coalesce(animals)`? If `animals` is `null` it will return `null`.

Comment: Animals is a column. Might make more sense if you look at the DB Fiddle.

Comment: Yes, I looked at the fiddle. COALESCE() is useful when you provide at least 2 values so that  the 2nd will be returned when the 1st is NULL. `coalesce(animals)` is equivalent to just `animals`.

Comment: Thanks! Is there another function that would achieve what I’m looking for?

Comment: You did not explain what you are looking for. Post your expected output.

Comment: The expected output would be either “lion” or “tiger” but not any of the 8 null rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have mis-understanding with the `COALESCE` function! You can use multiple columns as parameter while using this function like `COALESCE(col1, col2, col3)`. It returns the first non null value in case of using more than one column as parameter. To understand, please see the [SQL Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e3e8d5/2)

[More detail here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-coalesce/)

According to your comment, I think you are looking for this :

```
SELECT animals from list where animals is not null ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a function that would achieve it?

Comment: What is your expected output based on the values available in the table using `SELECT coalesce(animals)` ?

Comment: The expected output would be either “lion” or “tiger”.

Comment: Try this: SELECT animals from list where animals is not null ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `COALESCE()`.
Just filter out the `NULL`s from the table `list`:

```
SET NEW.random = ( SELECT animals
                   FROM list
                   WHERE animals IS NOT NULL
                   ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 );
```

See the result in your [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d69515ff5ce0f5e4b841ee6274073c1b).